# Application to support multiple screen resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

[image]

I have 3 layout folders in my project:

**1. layout**

**2. layout-large**

**3. layout-small**

and as of now i don't have anything in **layout-small** but **layout** has layouts with small dimensions and **layout-large** has layouts with large dimensions.

The problem is:

when i test my app on a **240x320** it uses layouts from **layout**

when i test my app on a **480x800** even now it uses layouts from **layout**

Is it because thought i have **layout-large, 480x800** doesn't fall into large screens, hence uses the default **layout** folder?

If that is the case, how can i make layouts for **Normal Screens** there is nothing like **layout-normal** or **layout-medium**.

Moreover, if i design my layout for **HVGA (320x480)** it should work perfectly for **WVGA800 (480x800)** since they both fall under same screen size, only density changes. And i am using **dp** everywhere. Am i right?

any help appreciated.

Comment: As usual, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13190408/1487822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to *xlarge, large and small* then it is depending on *size*(inches) not on *dpi* of your device 
see below for specification

[image]

Additionally *DPI* is basically for Drawables while *SIZE* is for Layout.

Comment: To be specific. 1 Major problem i face is: I ahve an image which must be **Match_parent** in width and **Half the parent** in height. So in layout i will use a 9-patch with **width = match_parent**, but how to set the height here?? probably ill set **height = 160dp** considering **HVGA (320x480)** this wont work with **WVGA800 (480x800)**

Comment: No, You should use LinearLayout as a base and in child work with `Weight` property.

Comment: eww. So every layout must use only LinearLayout with appropriate weights, if i got to support all the screen sizes?. so far i am using RelativeLayouts, if i have to change them to LinearLayouts it will be triple the code :(

Comment: No, It depends. You need to decide when to use Relative/Linear but Linear works perfect when you give control area proportionately.  Dont change simple create a sample project and learn LinearLayout you will definitely get to know when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following details it may work but i am not sure..

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Just try....

Comment: is there anything for normal too?? **layout-normal** ??

Comment: type layout is always layout normal

Answer (score 0):

You should check this developer page out it helped me alot. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Even if they have different resolution or screen size that doesnt mean that they have different pixel density. For example a large screen may have less pixel density than a smaller screen.

Another example would be the Samsung Galaxy tab which is 10.1 inch but is still mdpi-large and Nexus One which is less than 5 inch but uses hdpi.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what is going wrong with you........ lets try this.
suppose you are going to make the application compatible for 480x800 resolution.So for that first of all create two folder for it i.e.

1.layout-sw480dp this is for landscape.

2.layout-sw480dp-port for portrait mode.

Now,put all layout of the resolution of 480X800  in it.you see it will run easily on the particular resolution.

Note:- point here to be noted that for any device resolution let A X B. the name of the layout folder is goes like this.

1.layout-swAdp.

2.layout-swAdp-port.

here "A" is the screen resolution height value of device.

i hope it work for you.